# R: t-test for each pairwise combination of a grouping variable, done for every element in an ID variable

Tags: r, dataframe, testing, data.table, purrr

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010961/t-test-on-all-group-combinations-of-one-column-inside-dataframe), I am trying to add one more layer of difficulty.

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
> set.seed(123)
> mydf <- data.frame(Marker=rep(c('M1','M2'),each=15),
+                    Patient=rep(rep(c('P1','P2','P3'),each=5),2),
+                    Value=sample(1:1000, 30, replace = F))
> mydf
   Marker Patient Value
1      M1      P1   288
2      M1      P1   788
3      M1      P1   409
4      M1      P1   881
5      M1      P1   937
6      M1      P2    46
7      M1      P2   525
8      M1      P2   887
9      M1      P2   548
10     M1      P2   453
11     M1      P3   948
12     M1      P3   449
13     M1      P3   670
14     M1      P3   566
15     M1      P3   102
16     M2      P1   993
17     M2      P1   243
18     M2      P1    42
19     M2      P1   323
20     M2      P1   996
21     M2      P2   872
22     M2      P2   679
23     M2      P2   627
24     M2      P2   972
25     M2      P2   640
26     M2      P3   691
27     M2      P3   530
28     M2      P3   579
29     M2      P3   282
30     M2      P3   143
```

What I want to do, is to run `t.test` for each **Patient** combination (my grouping variable), on a **Marker** basis (my ID variable).

Based on one answer to the related question above, I know how to do it for one **Marker** at a time.

I can subset `mydf` and do the following:

```
> params_list <- utils::combn(levels(mydf$Patient), 2, FUN = list)
> mydf0 <- subset(mydf, Marker=="M1")
> model_t <- purrr::map(.x = params_list, 
+                       .f = ~ t.test(formula = Value ~ Patient, 
+                       data = subset(mydf0, Patient %in% .x)))
> t_pvals <- purrr::map_dbl(.x = model_t, .f  = "p.value")
> names(t_pvals) <- purrr::map_chr(.x = params_list, .f = ~ paste0(.x, collapse = "-vs-"))
> t_pvals
 P1-vs-P2  P1-vs-P3  P2-vs-P3 
0.3945742 0.5678729 0.7820905
```

Now I want to do it for all **Markers** in `mydf` in an elegant way, and I chose `data.table`.

I try the following, but I cannot reproduce the above pvalue results for **Marker M1**.

```
> group1 <- unlist(lapply(params_list, '[', 1))
> group2 <- unlist(lapply(params_list, '[', 2))
> mydt <- data.table::data.table(mydf)
> results_df <- as.data.frame(mydt[, list(group1= unlist(lapply(params_list, '[', 1)),
+                                         group2= unlist(lapply(params_list, '[', 2)),
+                                         pvalue= purrr::map_dbl(.x = purrr::map(.x = params_list,
+                                                 .f = ~ stats::t.test(formula = Value ~ Patient, paired=FALSE,
+                                                 data = subset(mydt, Patient %in% .x))), .f  = "p.value") ),
+                                  by=list(Marker=Marker)])
> results_df
  Marker group1 group2    pvalue
1     M1     P1     P2 0.8092365
2     M1     P1     P3 0.5156313
3     M1     P2     P3 0.2879954
4     M2     P1     P2 0.8092365
5     M2     P1     P3 0.5156313
6     M2     P2     P3 0.2879954
```

The structure of `results_df` is exactly as I want it, but the **pvalues** are clearly wrong. They are not the same as the ones in the test above for **M1**, and they are identical for **M1** and **M2**, meaning the same data subset is used in both cases.

I figured I should subset for each **Marker** as well in the `subset` command, so I did this instead:

```
> markers_list <- as.list(levels(mydf$Marker))
> mydt <- data.table::data.table(mydf)
> results_df <- as.data.frame(mydt[, list(group1= unlist(lapply(params_list, '[', 1)),
+                                         group2= unlist(lapply(params_list, '[', 2)),
+                                         pvalue= purrr::map_dbl(.x = purrr::map(.x = params_list, .y = markers_list,
+                                                 .f = ~ stats::t.test(formula = Value ~ Patient, paired=FALSE,
+                                                 data = subset(mydt, Patient %in% .x & Marker==.y))), .f  = "p.value") ),
+                                  by=list(Marker=Marker)])
> results_df
  Marker group1 group2    pvalue
1     M1     P1     P2 0.7337355
2     M1     P1     P3 0.6930669
3     M1     P2     P3 0.3788015
4     M2     P1     P2 0.7337355
5     M2     P1     P3 0.6930669
6     M2     P2     P3 0.3788015
```

I thought this would be it, but still I'm getting incorrect **pvalues**, and identical for both M1 and M2 (same data subset still being used for both)...

So now I'm clueless... What am I doing wrong here? What would be the way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option  in `data.table`:

```
mydf[, rbindlist(combn(split(Value, Patient), 2L, 
        function(x) c(as.list(names(x)), .(t.test(x[[1]], x[[2]])$p.value)), simplify=FALSE))
    , Marker]
```

output:

```
   Marker V1 V2        V3
1:     M1 P1 P2 0.3945742
2:     M1 P1 P3 0.5678729
3:     M1 P2 P3 0.7820905
4:     M2 P1 P2 0.3098955
5:     M2 P1 P3 0.7505371
6:     M2 P2 P3 0.0372944
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
mydf <- fread("
Marker Patient Value
M1      P1   288
M1      P1   788
M1      P1   409
M1      P1   881
M1      P1   937
M1      P2    46
M1      P2   525
M1      P2   887
M1      P2   548
M1      P2   453
M1      P3   948
M1      P3   449
M1      P3   670
M1      P3   566
M1      P3   102
M2      P1   993
M2      P1   243
M2      P1    42
M2      P1   323
M2      P1   996
M2      P2   872
M2      P2   679
M2      P2   627
M2      P2   972
M2      P2   640
M2      P3   691
M2      P3   530
M2      P3   579
M2      P3   282
M2      P3   143")
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this code a bit better, cause resembles a bit more the way I tried to do it... just a couple questions: 1) what does `2L` mean here? what's the difference with just `2`? - 2) I noticed if I do `group=as.list(names(x))...` I get `group1` and `group2` instead of `V1` and `V2` as I want... but how would I change the suffix? what if I wanted say `group_A` and `group_B`? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes 2L is integer 2. For the 2nd qn you acn use `setNames(as.list(names(x)), c("group_A","group_B"))`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `data.table`-solution

I could not reproduce your sample data, so I read in the values provided using `data.table::fread()`.

You could also use `data.table::setDT(mydf)` on your existing `mydf` to convert it to a data.table.

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
#setDT(mydf)   
mydf <- fread("   Marker Patient Value
      M1      P1   288
      M1      P1   788
      M1      P1   409
      M1      P1   881
      M1      P1   937
      M1      P2    46
      M1      P2   525
      M1      P2   887
      M1      P2   548
     M1      P2   453
     M1      P3   948
     M1      P3   449
     M1      P3   670
     M1      P3   566
     M1      P3   102
     M2      P1   993
     M2      P1   243
     M2      P1    42
     M2      P1   323
     M2      P1   996
     M2      P2   872
     M2      P2   679
     M2      P2   627
     M2      P2   972
     M2      P2   640
     M2      P3   691
     M2      P3   530
     M2      P3   579
     M2      P3   282
   M2      P3   143")
```

**code**

I added some brief explanation, and intermediate/temporary results in comments in the code. But it has become more comment than code ;-)...
Anyway, here we go...

```
mydf[, 
     #suppress immediate output using {}
     {
     # find all unique combinations of 2 patients (by Marker, see last line)
     # For Marker == "M1", this looks like:
      #    V1 V2
      # 1: P1 P2
      # 2: P1 P3
      # 3: P2 P3
     patientcomb <- data.table( t( combn( unique( Patient ), 2 ) ) )
     #set column names for V1 and V2 of patientcomb, for better readable code
     names( patientcomb ) <- c( "group1", "group2" )
     #now, using the temporarily created patientcomb-data.table...
     patientcomb[,
                 #... perform the t.test(), using the Values from mydf, 
                 #  where the patients match group1/group1
                 #remember, we are still grouped by Marker
                 data.table( p.value = t.test( Value[Patient == group1], 
                                               Value[Patient == group2])$p.value), 
                 #group by group1 and group2
                 by = .(group1, group2) ]
     # for Marker == M1, this looks like:
      #    group1 group2   p.value
      # 1:     P1     P2 0.3945742
      # 2:     P1     P3 0.5678729
      # 3:     P2     P3 0.7820905
     # for Marker == M2, this looks like:
      #    group1 group2   p.value
      # 1:     P1     P2 0.3098955
      # 2:     P1     P3 0.7505371
      # 3:     P2     P3 0.0372944
     }, 
    #main grouping by Marker
    by = .(Marker) ]
```

**output**

seems to match desired output

```
#    Marker group1 group2   p.value
# 1:     M1     P1     P2 0.3945742
# 2:     M1     P1     P3 0.5678729
# 3:     M1     P2     P3 0.7820905
# 4:     M2     P1     P2 0.3098955
# 5:     M2     P1     P3 0.7505371
# 6:     M2     P2     P3 0.0372944
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one `tidyverse` approach :

```
library(tidyverse)

get_p_value <- function(df) {
   map_df(params_list,  ~{
     tibble(Marker = df[[1]][1], group1 = .x[1], group2 = .x[2], 
       pvalue =  t.test(df$Value[df$Patient == .x[1]], 
                        df$Value[df$Patient == .x[2]])$p.value)
      })
}

mydf %>% group_split(Marker) %>% map_df(get_p_value)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  Marker group1 group2 pvalue
#  <fct>  <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 M1     P1     P2     0.395 
#2 M1     P1     P3     0.568 
#3 M1     P2     P3     0.782 
#4 M2     P1     P2     0.310 
#5 M2     P1     P3     0.751 
#6 M2     P2     P3     0.0373
```

where `params_list` is from OP.

```
params_list <- utils::combn(levels(mydf$Patient), 2, FUN = list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pairwise.t.test()` on the data grouped by `Marker` seems a better way to approach this and avoids the need to explicitly generate the `Patient` combinations.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  group_by(Marker) %>%
  summarise(x = list(pairwise.t.test(Value, Patient, p.adjust.method = "none", pool.sd = FALSE)$p.value %>% as.data.frame.table(responseName = "p.value"))) %>%
  unnest(x) %>%
  filter(!is.na(p.value))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Marker Var1  Var2  p.value
  <fct>  <fct> <fct>   <dbl>
1 M1     P2    P1     0.395 
2 M1     P3    P1     0.568 
3 M1     P3    P2     0.782 
4 M2     P2    P1     0.310 
5 M2     P3    P1     0.751 
6 M2     P3    P2     0.0373
```

In response to your comment, there is also a pairwise version of the wilcox test:

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(Marker) %>%
  summarise(x = list(pairwise.wilcox.test(Value, Patient, p.adjust.method = "none")$p.value %>% as.data.frame.table(responseName = "p.value"))) %>%
  unnest(x) %>%
  filter(!is.na(p.value))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Marker Var1  Var2  p.value
  <fct>  <fct> <fct>   <dbl>
1 M1     P2    P1     0.690 
2 M1     P3    P1     0.841 
3 M1     P3    P2     0.690 
4 M2     P2    P1     0.690 
5 M2     P3    P1     1     
6 M2     P3    P2     0.0556
```

Comment: well in my real life data it's actually `wilcox.test` most of the times (I just used `t.test` in the MWE to make it easier to understand)... but is there actually a non-parametric equivalent of `pairwise.t.test()`?

Comment: @DaniCee- there is indeed a function for a pairwise version of the wilcox test - it works in the same way. I've edited in an example.

Comment: I have a general question regarding `pairwise.t.test`, see if you can help me with... I usually test for equal variances using Levene's test; besides, sometimes data comes from same patients so I assume it's paired. As such, if variances are equal for each marker and grouping variable level, I would run `t.test` with `var.equal=TRUE` and `paired=TRUE` (is that correct?)... However, `pairwise.t.test` does not allow for both `pool.sd` and `paired` to be `TRUE`

Comment: @DaniCee - No that's not correct.  A paired t-test is equivalent to a one sample t-test against a true mean of zero.  In `t.test(..., paired = TRUE)` then also setting `var.equal = TRUE` results in this argument being silently ignored because a single source of variance can't be pooled. You'll see you get exactly the same result when `paired = TRUE` irrespective of `var.equal` being `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  I think `pairwise.t.test()` handles this better by preventing these arguments from both being true.

Comment: oooohhh alright! one more reason to switch then. Many thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be the way to do this with data.table in the same way I was trying? I've been tinkering around but cannot crack it...

Comment: @DaniCee - I don't have much data.table knowledge but this seems to work: `mydt[, na.omit(as.data.frame.table(pairwise.wilcox.test(Value, Patient, p.adjust.method = "none")$p.value, responseName = "p.value" ))
     , Marker]`